# Retrieving Multiple Data Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new in firebase, so I'm trying to know how can get all the names of each of the products in the table Products, thank you

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the `name`, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference productsRef = rootRef.child("Products");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", name);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
productsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
ps4
Asus
galaxy 8
```